# Assembly Memory Diagram Verification

Tags: memory, assembly, diagram

Given this data,

```
  .data
  Alpha WORD 0022h, 45h
  Beta BYTE 56h
  Gamma DWORD 4567h
  Delta BYTE 23h
```

Assuming that the data segment begins at 0x00404000, can anyone verify how correct this table is?

```
Address     Variable    Data
00404000    Alpha       22
00404001    Alpha + 1   00
00404002    Alpha + 2   45
00404003    Beta        56
00404004    Gamma       67
00404005    Gamma+1     45
00404006    Delta       23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to answer without knowing the addressing of the processor in question (and how the assembler views the addressing). Nonetheless, you'd need a pretty unusual system for it to be correct.

Alpha is defined has having the type "word". You're showing the first word as allocating two bytes (fairly reasonable), but the second only one byte. This is much less reasonable--a word might be one byte or it might be two, but its size is normally going to at least be consistent.

For the moment, let's assume a word is two bytes, and a dword is four bytes. In that case, I'd expect something more like:

```
Alpha   22h
alpha+1 00h
alpha+2 45h
Alpha+3 00h
Beta    56h
Gamma   67h
Gamma+1 45h
Gamma+2 00h
Gamma+3 00h
Delta   23h
```